# how to save an array to file and load and ask if it contains a specific file

Tags: iphone

i have this array called favorites referenced in my app delegate.
When i access it in the view controller i use this code

```
MultiViewAppDelegate *app = (MultiViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.favoritesArray addObject:@"one"];
```

And in the table thats supposed to display this information im trying to ask if the array contains a certain element and if it does to display that item using this code.

```
NSLog (@"2");
favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

didContain = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSLog (@"3");

if ([favoritesArray containsObject:@"one"])

{[didContain addObject:@"one"];
NSLog (@"4"); }
```

however the code isnt running after nslog 3...
can someone inform me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

```
NSLog (@"2");
favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

The above line will reset your favoritesArray. It will also leak the old one.

```
didContain = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSLog (@"3");

if ([favoritesArray containsObject:@"one"])
```

Here, you're simply asking an empty array if it contains something, which it obviously doesn't.

```
{[didContain addObject:@"one"];
NSLog (@"4"); }
```

Which is why none of the above ever happens.

Instead of resetting it, make sure it's set instead.

```
if (favoritesArray != nil && 
    [favoritesArray containsObject:@"one"]) {
    NSLog(@"yay, it had one in it");
} else {
    NSLog(@"it's nil or it didn't have one in it");
}
```

You probably don't need `favoritesArray != nil`, but I put it in because you might have put your alloc-init stuff in because you sometimes get a nil value here. Unlikely though.

```
if ([favoritesArray containsObject:@"one"]) {
    // contains "one"
}
```

That should probably do it.

Comment: If `favoritesArray` is nil then `[favoritesArray containsObject:@"one"]` will always return NO, so you are correct when you say the nil check isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `favoritesArray` in your delegate is initialized. If it is `nil`, the condition will never be true.

Comment: i have it under 
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
 [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    favoritesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

however what do i need to add the array in both of the headers and synthesize it ?